# Is there a way to convert an AutomationElement to a UIElement?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface

I am very new to programming with WPF so this may be a simple question. I have an AutomationElement and would like to convert it to a UIElement (or even a DependencyObject) so that I can trigger a key pressed event using

```
public KeyEventArgs(KeyboardDevice keyboard, PresentationSource inputSource, int timestamp, Key key);
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What do you want to achieve with the key pressed event? Text input in a `Textbox`?

Comment: @Roel thanks for your question. I am trying to send it to web browser control.